# Two datasets with same length give different number of extremes

Tags: r, probability, density-function, quantiles, extreme-value

I have two datasets of a given variable `x` that have the same length, let's say 14600 values in total each one.

I need to extract the extreme observations within each dataset, where extremes means values > 99th percentile.

I do this by using the R function `quantile` as follows, where `df_1` and `df_2` are the two datasets:

```
df_1_q99 = quantile(df_1$x, probs = 0.99)
df_1_extr = subset(df_1, x > df_1_q99[[1]])

df_2_q99 = quantile(df_2$x, probs = 0.99)
df_2_extr = subset(df_2, x > df_2_q99[[1]])
```

The issue, which does not make sense to me, is that for `df_1` I obtain `n=84` and for `df_2` `n=126` extreme values.

Shouldn't the number of extremes be the same since the two datasets have the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only true if each observation has a distinct value. When there are ties you can easily get the pattern you saw.